# Using custom nameservers

Tags: centos, bind, nameserver, hostname, named-conf

In Godaddy I have a domain example1.com and [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) with valid A record to my Centos 7 server's IP.

I 've created hostnames for that domain, ns1.example1.com, ns2.example1.com with the same server IP.

I have another doamin example2.com in Godaddy in which I want to use the custom nameservers. So I put in the nameserver field ns1.example1.com and ns2.example1.com.

In my server's named.conf

```
  zone "example2.com" IN {
     type master;
     file "/etc/named/foo.zone";
     allow-update { none; };
 };
```

In foo.zone:

```
 $TTL 600
 @                    3600 SOA   example2.com (
        example2.com.     ; address of responsible party
        2016072701                 ; serial number
        3600                       ; refresh period
        600                        ; retry period
        604800                     ; expire time
        1800                     ) ; minimum ttl
        86400 NS    example2.com.
        14400 A 1.2.3.4
        mail  14400 A     1.2.3.4
```

I expected then that example2.com and mail.example2.com to resolve to 1.2.3.4.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment

---

> What am I doing wrong ?

You can validate syntax of zone files with [`named-checkzone`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/named-checkzone) `zone-name`   `/path/to/zone.file` i.e.

```
named-checkzone example2.com  /etc/named/foo.zone
```

You can validate the syntax for your `named.conf`  configuration file with [`named-checkconf`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/named-checkconf):

```
named-checkconf /path/to/named.conf
```

**Note** that a valid syntax can still result in logical/functional errors and incorrectly behaving resource records.

---

```
@                    3600 SOA   example2.com (  ;<=== MISSING FIELD
```

In the  [SOA record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOA_record) a field is missing.

The first field is called the MNAME record. The MNAME record must be a name-server that will respond authoritatively for your domain.

The second field is the RNAME record, the
email address of the administrator responsible for this zone. (As usual, the email address is encoded as a name. The part of the email address before the <kbd>@</kbd> becomes the first label of the name; the domain name after the <kbd>@</kbd> becomes the rest of the name. In zone-file format, dots in labels are escaped with backslashes; thus the email address `john.doe@example.com` would be represented in a zone file as `john\.doe.example.com.`)

---

Be careful with [zone file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) shorthand

```
      86400 NS    example2.com. ; STARTING A LINE WITH A BLANK IS VALID SHORTHAND

@  IN 86400 NS    example2.com. ; This is less likely to misbehave
```

It might be an artefact of how you formatted your question, but the formatting of zone files has meaning (starting a line with a blank name for example makes the line a continuation of the previous resource record name) and having  `mail` aligned with `14400` is wrong.

```
      14400 A 1.2.3.4
      mail  14400 A     1.2.3.4  ; this alignment is incorrect
mail  14400 A     1.2.3.4        ; there should be no space/tab before mail
```